# GIT: Restoring a file in a pull request to its latest from master branch to resolve conflicts

Tags: git

I made a pull request to merge my branch XML_PUSH into master branch with following files:

```
1.xml
2.xml
3.xml
```

Before my PR got completed, some one else merged 3.xml in the master branch with those changes. So it conflicted and I was unable to merge 2 and 3 xml's.

Now what i would simply like to do is delete the master branch from the PR without closing it (since there are already many review comments in there).

I have tried several commands but unable to accomplish this.
Kindly provide some direction.

Comment: Resolve the conflict (edit `3.xml`, make it look as you please, add it to index) then run `git merge --continue`. (`git status` probably suggests the same)

Comment: After merging this is what I get:
error: merge is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. In order to resolve a conflict on a file you have to put the file in the state you want (by editing it directly, by checking it out from one of the branches you want to merge etc) then `git add` it. Or use `git rm` if deletion is the correct way to solve the conflict for it.

Comment: Thanks got it - bit new to git so wasn't aware of fixing the merge in editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what i followed to fix this:

```
git checkout destination-branch-name 
git pull origin destination-branch-name
git checkout source-branch-name
git merge destination-branch-name
```

Expected output will be like:

> computer:space-repository dstevens$ git merge development Auto-merging
>
> contributors.txt CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in
>
> contributors.txt Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit
>
> the result.

File will be opened in default text editor (in my case it was DOS envt editor) and resolve the conflict.
There will be sections for Head and Development like:

```
> <<<<<<<<<< HEAD Head text
> ==============
> >>>>>> DEVELOPMENT Conflicting Development Text
```

Resolve the conflict by doing the following:

Correct the content.
Remove the change designations added by Git (1, 2, and 3).
Save the file.
Add and commit the change

```
git add filename.txt
git commit -m'commit message'
```

Push the change to the remote.

```
git push origin source-branch-name
```

Refresh Pull Request in browser and observe the changes

Answer (score 1):

> Now what I would simply like to do is delete the master branch from the PR without closing it

Simply rebase your PR branch on top of the original repo `master` branch: make sure you have a remote called '`upstream`' referencing said original repo (ie the repo that you have forked, with remote '`origin`' pointing to your fork)

```
git remote -v
# if upstream is missing:
git remote add upstream /url/to/original/repo

git fetch upstream
git checkout my_pr_branch
git rebase upstream/master
```

That should give you conflicts (check with git status)

Resolve those conflicts by editing the files and removing the merge markers.
See "[Resolving a merge conflict from the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/)".

Then:

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

Once the rebase is done, force push your PR branch and the same PR will be submitted with its new history.

```
git push --force
```

Comment: when we say upstream - does it change on the server or locally in the following command:
git remote add upstream /url/to/original/repo

Comment: @user1570408 No it is purely a local setting.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way will be to use git checkout.

In your case git checkout origin/master